# Width DialogFragment in Android 4 and Android 2

Tags: android, dialogfragment

I make DialogFragment with choice by TableLayout.
In Android 2.3.3 it's show as I want - width=wrap content (but divide doesn't show).

http://prntscr.com/296xvr

But when I test it Android 4 width of my layout stretch to screen width. 
http://prntscr.com/296y99

How to make width for dialog fragment the same as it shown in android 2.3.3?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="200dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:baselineAligned="false"
              android:measureWithLargestChild="false" android:showDividers="middle" android:clickable="true"
              android:divider="@drawable/line">

    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:clickable="true" android:onClick="onClick" android:id="@+id/trVolume">
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView" android:src="@drawable/volume" android:contentDescription="s"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView" android:text="@string/lblVolume" android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/trLength">
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2" android:src="@drawable/length" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/lblLength"
                android:id="@+id/textView2" android:paddingLeft="20dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_vertical|left" android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/trWeight">
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3" android:src="@drawable/weight" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/lblWeight"
                android:id="@+id/textView3" android:paddingLeft="20dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_vertical|left" android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/trArea">
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView4" android:src="@drawable/area" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/lblArea"
                android:id="@+id/textView4" android:paddingLeft="20dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 getDialog().setTitle(getString(R.string.selectConv));

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.unit_conv_select, null);
        return v;
}
```

Comment: change the theme of the dialog, the reason it is streching out more than you want in 4.0 is because the title sets it to a minimum width when there is one

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean? As I understand Title in dialog fragment in has a width = full screen width? Because I try to set style with no title - but situation the same.